# Image does not display in JSP

Tags: java, image, jsp

I created a dynamic web project in order to show a JSP via a Servlet (I cannot use any Frameworks like Spring...). By default, my built classes were placed in Build/classes, so after I changed the output folder to WebContent/WEB-INF/classes, my app is running fine. Afterword I converted the project to a Maven Project. (I don't remember that I needed to change the output folder the last time I worked with Servlets/JSP which was 3 years ago!).

Anyway, now I cannot display an image in my page, I placed the image in WebContent/images/logo.jpg and also in /images/logo.jpg (neither locations worked!)

This is what I added to the JSP to display the image

```
<img alt="1" src="/images/logo.jpg" width="88"> 
<img alt="2" src="images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="3" src="<c:url value='/images/logo.jpg'/>" width="88">
<img alt="4" src="<c:url value='images/logo.jpg'/>" width="88">
<img alt="5" src="/<c:url value='/images/logo.jpg'/>" width="88">
<img alt="6" src="/<c:url value='images/logo.jpg'/>" width="88">
<img alt="7" src="<% request.getContextPath(); %>/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="8" src="<% request.getContextPath(); %>images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="9" src="/<% request.getContextPath(); %>/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="A" src="/<% request.getContextPath(); %>images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="B" src="/WebContent/images/logo.jpg" width="88"> 
<img alt="C" src="WebContent/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="D" src="<c:url value='/WebContent/images/logo.jpg'/>" width="88">
<img alt="E" src="<c:url value='WebContent/images/logo.jpg'/>" width="88">
<img alt="F" src="/<c:url value='/WebContent/images/logo.jpg'/>" width="88">
<img alt="G" src="/<c:url value='WebContent/images/logo.jpg'/>" width="88">
<img alt="H" src="<% request.getContextPath(); %>/WebContent/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="I" src="<% request.getContextPath(); %>WebContent/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="J" src="/<% request.getContextPath(); %>/WebContent/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="K" src="<% request.getContextPath(); %>WebContent/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="L" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WebContent/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="M" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}WebContent/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="N" src="/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WebContent/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="O" src="/${pageContext.request.contextPath}WebContent/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="P" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="Q" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="R" src="/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/logo.jpg" width="88">
<img alt="S" src="/${pageContext.request.contextPath}images/logo.jpg" width="88">
```

I also added this line to the jsp to debug the contextPath

```
<c:url value='images/logo.jpg'/><br /><br /> <!-- shows: images/logo.jpg -->
<% request.getContextPath(); %> <br />       <!-- shows nothing! in the JSP but shows /GraphGenerator from the servlet (using sysout)-->
${pageContext.request.contextPath} <br />    <!-- shows: /GraphsGenerator (name of the project as displayed in the url http:localhost:8080/GraphsGenerator/ -->
```

This is the structure of the project:

[image]

I'm using :

- Java 8.
- Eclipse IDE.
- Dynamic web module v3.1.
- Tomcat v9.0 server

If you can find a solution (and an explanation would be nice too) I'll be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a folder resources in your scr folder and add your images in there

```
 |-- pom.xml
 `-- src
     `-- main
         |-- java
         |   `-- com
         |       `-- example
         |           `-- projects
         |               `-- SampleAction.java
         |-- resources
         |   `-- images
         |       `-- sampleimage.jpg // Add your image here
         `-- webapp
             |-- WEB-INF
             |   `-- web.xml
             |-- index.jsp
             `-- jsp
                 `-- websource.jsp
```

This is the basic sctructure of maven and it will genereate a war with this structure

```
  |-- META-INF
  |   |-- MANIFEST.MF
  |   `-- maven
  |       `-- com.example.projects
  |           `-- documentedproject
  |               |-- pom.properties
  |               `-- pom.xml
  |-- WEB-INF
  |   |-- classes
  |   |   |-- com
  |   |   |   `-- example
  |   |   |       `-- projects
  |   |   |           `-- SampleAction.class
  |   |   `-- images
  |   |       `-- sampleimage.jpg
  |   `-- web.xml
  |-- index.jsp
  `-- jsp
      `-- websource.jsp
```

From [Maven Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: 1- I don't have a webapp folder inside src/main, I have a WebContent folder in the root
2 - I created the webapp folder and added the image in the resources folder, then used the following to display the image and still can't display it (i used the following links : "/logo.jpg", "/resources/logo.jpg", "/main/resources/logo.jpg" & "/src/main/resources/logo.jpg")

Comment: No you need to use this one <img alt="1" src="/images/logo.jpg" width="88">

Comment: Sir, with all due respect, you solution isn't working. There is no images folder, I placed the image directly under resources and tried different possible links with no luck.